# How to write Android ViewModel properly and move logic out of it?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewbinding

I'm trying to use MVVM with `ViewModel`, `ViewBinding`, Retrofit2 in Android/Kotlin.

I don't know how to move application logic from `ViewModel`. I can't just move methods with logic because they run on viewModelScope and put results into observable objects in my `ViewModel`.

Or maybe I can?

For example I have some ArrayList (to show on some ListView).

```
// items ArrayList
private val _stocktakings = 
    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<InventoryStocktakingWithCountsDto?>>(ArrayList())
val stocktakings : LiveData<ArrayList<InventoryStocktakingWithCountsDto?>> get() =
_stocktakings

// selected item
private val _selected_stocktaking = MutableLiveData<Int>>
val selected_stocktaking : LiveData<Int> get() = _selected_stocktaking
```

And a function that is called from my fragment:

```
public fun loadStocktakings() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        Log.d(TAG, "Load stocktakings requested")
        clearError()
        try {
            with(ApiResponse(ApiAdapter.apiClient.findAllStocktakings())){
                if (isSuccessful && body != null){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Load Stocktakings done")
                    setStocktakings(body)
                } else {
                    val e = "Can't load stocktakings, API error: {${errorMessage}}"
                    Log.e(TAG, e)
                    HandleError("Can't load stocktakings, API error: {${e}}") // puts error message into val lastError MutableLiveData...
                }
            }
        } catch (t : Throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't load stocktakings, connectivity error: ${t.message}")
            HandleError("Can't load stocktakings, API error: {${e}}") // puts error message into val lastError MutableLiveData...
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to add another function that changes some field in one of `stocktakings`. Maybe something like:

```
public fun setSelectedStocktakingComplete() {
    stocktakings.value[selected_stocktaking.value].isComplete = true;

    // call some API function... another 15 lines of code?
}
```

**How to do it properly?**

I feel I have read wrong tutorials... This will end with fat viewmodel cluttered with `viewModelScope.launch`, error handling and I can't imagine what will happen when I start adding data/form validation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, some tip for that

1. Make sure the ViewModel is only responsible for holding and managing
   UI-related data.
2. Avoid putting business logic in the ViewModel. Instead, encapsulate
   it in separate classes, such as Repository or Interactor classes.
3. Use LiveData to observe data changes in the ViewModel and update the
   UI accordingly.
4. Avoid making network or database calls in the ViewModel. Instead,
   use the Repository pattern to manage data operations and provide the
   data to the ViewModel through a LiveData or other observable object.
5. Make sure the ViewModel does not hold context references, such as
   Activity or Fragment.
6. Use a ViewModel factory to provide dependencies to the ViewModel, if
   necessary.
7. you can ensure that your ViewModel is simple, easy to test,
   and scalable. It also makes it easier to maintain your codebase, as
   the business logic is separated from the UI logic.

hope you understand

Comment: Well, I think I understand the idea, but I don't know how to do/organize Interactor and Repository classes. For example I need one Repository, one Interactor and they should be able to communicate. Should I put them both inside "top level" Interactor?

Comment: When I want to use repository pattern I shoud pass viewModelScope to my repository method which I'm calling or thru repository constructor?

Comment: It depends on how you want to manage the lifecycle of the coroutines within your repository. If you want to tie the lifecycle of the coroutines to the lifecycle of a specific ViewModel, you should pass the viewModelScope to the repository methods that you are calling.

Comment: This allows the coroutines to be cancelled when the ViewModel is destroyed, which helps prevent memory leaks. On the other hand, if you don't have a specific ViewModel associated with the repository, or if you want the coroutines to have a longer lifecycle, you can create a custom CoroutineScope for the repository and pass it through the constructor.

Comment: It depends on your specific use case and design choices. One common approach is to have a separate Interactor and Repository class, and to have the Interactor class depend on the Repository. In this case, the Interactor acts as a mediator between the view (e.g. an Activity or Fragment) and the Repository.

Comment: The Interactor would be responsible for handling the business logic and making calls to the Repository to retrieve or persist data. The Repository would be responsible for managing the data, for example by fetching it from a local database or a remote API.

Comment: By keeping the Interactor and Repository separate, you can maintain a clean separation of concerns and make it easier to test and maintain your code. You can also reuse the Repository in other parts of the app without having to duplicate the business logic.

Comment: So Interactor classes are extra layer between ViewModel and Repository. Thank you for exhaustive explanation.

Comment: for better understanding just do it in code